# How to set up the MessageSelector in activeMq

Tags: c#, apache-nms

I have a process that runs and polls for a message in an ActiveMQ.
Now I have problems with setting up the message selector.
The Queue is connected and pulls messages from the Queue, without selector.

If I add an selector, it just breaks with a exception that only contains the selector string.

As much as I read the thin documentation I don't really get the problem, I played with masking the string and played with the format, but no luck.

The Message in the Queue has the following property/value pair as one of its properties, as I can see the message in the webpanel in the queue:

F_IMGKOMP.PIMG_SOURCE_FILENAME = EURDE_500.jpeg

The reduced code looks like this:

```
var selector = "F_IMGKOMP.PIMG_SOURCE_FILENAME = 'EURDE_500.jpeg'";

using (IMessageConsumer myCons = mySession.CreateConsumer(myDest, selector ))
{
    var tmp = myCons.Receive(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));

    if (tmp != null)
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("eureka");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector string is invalid which is why you get the error about the selector.  The selector syntax is SQL 92.

The identifier must obey the following rule:

> An identifier is an unlimited length sequence of Java letters and Java
> digits, the first of which must be a Java letter. A letter is any
> character for which the method Character.isJavaLetter returns true.
> This includes _ and $. A letter or digit is any character for which
> the method Character.isJavaLetterOrDigit returns true.

This implies that the use of the '.' in your selector property identifier is the culprit.